# Dividing site into 2 columns with textwrap

Tags: html, css, administration

This is my [admin panel](http://tristans.tk/admin) and I want to divide it into 2 columns with divs. The left div is a menu and has this style set:

```
#menu_left{
position: fixed;
float: left;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: #666;
color: white;
}
```

The right one is the content and has this style:

```
#content{
text-wrap: unrestricted;
float:left;
width: 100%;
    left: 300px;
}
```

It doesn't work as it should work, I want it to wrap the text, but it doesn't.
Tell me also please, if there is any faulty style setting.

Oh the html:

```
<body>
    <div id="menu_left">
        <h1>Menu</h1> <hr />
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have width 100% on content, which makes it stick out 300px to the right of the window, because of the width of `#menu_left`. You should make this some pixel value, or change `#menu_left` to a % width, say 20%, then content could be 80% and they would fit nicely.

Plus you should remove `left: 300px;` from `#content`, it will already go where you want it to because of the `float: left;`.

Comment: left: 300px needs to be there, cause of the position:fixed; or else it jumps to the left. Can I use javascript to return the window width of browsers? and then make the width of #content in pixels?

Comment: I'm going to make and <noscript> tag and I think that's about it. I thought there is a more elegant solution for this.

Comment: It is difficult to mix percentages with pixel values, without using JS.

Comment: I made it now as I wanted it. I used jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

Just clear out these lines and you should be good to go.

```
#menu_left{
position: fixed; <--don't need
float: left;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
top: 0; <--don't need
left: 0; <--don't need
background: #666;
color: white;
}

#content{
text-wrap: unrestricted; <--don't need (you really want to break letters in the same word?)
float:left;
width: 100%;
left: 300px; <--don't need
}
```

Using a pre-made system makes a lot more sense than trying to start from scratch.  I would recommend using a css system like grid960 http://960.gs/

Comment: I totally disagree with this, templates are constricting and aren't great teachers. And your going to have garbage, its part of the process of learning. You have to try stuff to see what it does.

Comment: You don't need to try text-wrap: unrestricted to know what it does. I am a big fan of reading through documentation. Take time to learn how to do it right the first time. You aren't going to get everything right away but do your homework is what I am saying. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/

Comment: I am doing this to learn for myself, I love to start from scratch. I feel more comfortable with my own code, than with someone elses. 
And the "fix" you posted doesn't work. I'm going to stick with js/jquery.